# python - numpy create array from multiple files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 50 research subjects who provided reaction time data on six tasks. I stored each subject's mean reaction time on a task as a .npy file (50 subjects * 6 tasks = 300 files), and I wish to get a group mean for each task. This would ideally result in six files for the group.

To put it another way, I want to populate a numpy array with individual .npy files, but I am a little lost on the best way to do this.  I had the idea to initialize an empty array for each task, populate it with values for subjects, then get the mean.

```
subjects=range(1,51)
tasks=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
datalist=[]

for subject in subjects:
    for task in tasks:

        array=np.array(datalist)
        f=np.load('%d/%s.npy' % (subject,event))
        result=np.append(array,f)
        mu=np.mean(result)
        sav=np.save('%s' %(task),mu)
```

The result of this code is the last value in the series, indicating that the array is not populating correctly. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "the result of this code"? What gets saved? All that will get saved is a single value (the mean of the whole list). Are you sure that's not what's getting saved?

Comment: Right, so I did one by hand, for comparison, and can verify that the mean is different from what is being saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're recreating a new array each time, since it is inside the for loop. In fact, you are creating `array`, appending a single array to it, taking the mean, and then saving, for every single subject and every single task. You should instead organize it like this:

```
for task in tasks:
    result=np.array([])
    for subject in subjects:
        f=np.load('%d/%s.npy' % (subject,event))
        result=np.append(result,f)
    mu=np.mean(result)
    sav=np.save('%s' %(task),mu)
```

ETA: Incidentally, there are *much* better ways to store this data than in 300 separate .npy files. Is there only one value for each subject for each task? In that case, why not just represent this a 50 by 6 numpy matrix?

Comment: My experience with numpy is limited, but that does seem like a better solution.  I liked the idea of having a file that could be used as a basis for additional analyses in the future without having to recreate the original reaction time calculations.

Comment: You can still save the 50 by 6 matrix in a file. And then it's just one file instead of 300!

Comment: Hmm, I seem to get the same result from your code. I only see the last value in the series, but not the mean.

Comment: But again- you should *really* get it into a matrix. If it's in a matrix `m` with 50 rows and 6 columns, all you'll need to do is `np.mean(m, axis=1)` and you'll have all 6 means of each column.

Comment: Y'all, we should keep in mind it's a bad idea to append to a `np.array`. You should just create a basic list `result=[]`, append to this list, **then** create an array and take its mean.